# Can I take this sign(一) out of these words 一丝不苟 and "不屑一顾 or no?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, sentence

I'd like to know if that's optional take or not this sign, because i'm known that a few idioms are used to have this sign, thus i want to know why do they use this and how does it affect the sentence ?

Comment: What sign?   "一"  is a character  that means "one"

Answer (score 5):

These are both idioms (成语) with fixed structures, so deleting the 一 (yī) = ["one"](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%B8%80/) would change the meaning, and make it nonsensical.  This also holds for Chinese words such as [一起](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%B8%80%E8%B5%B7) and [第一](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%AC%AC%E4%B8%80).

- [**一**丝不苟](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%9D%E4%B8%8D%E8%8B%9F) basically means "[even] **one** thread not careless", referring to meticulousness.
- [不屑**一**顾](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%B8%8D%E5%B1%91%E4%B8%80%E9%A1%BE) basically means "disdain [even] **one** consideration", or "disdain even considering it once".  However, here it's possible to just say [不屑](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E4%B8%8D%E5%B1%91) = "disdain".

So ordinarily dropping the 一 is not reasonable, and certainly so among fixed idioms.

However, in some non-idiom cases we can drop the 一, such as:

- [每一个人](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%AF%8F%E4%B8%80%E4%B8%AA%E4%BA%BA) can be shorted to [每个人](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E6%AF%8F%E4%B8%AA%E4%BA%BA), and
- 她是一个医生 can be shorted to 她是个医生, and even further to 她是医生.

In these cases it's different: we have a [measure word](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Measure_words_for_counting) (个) and it's possible to sometimes drop the 一.

Comment: I don't think  someone who  learned the characters 丝, 苟, 屑 and 顾  would not had learned  the character 一 .